# Open an app on local pc from website - angular/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Is it possible to start an app on the PC e.g. Ubuntu Terminal, from a website. For example, after pressing a button, the app should be opened directly on the PC.

An example is the login in Jetbrains. If you log in, the Jetbrains app will open automatically.

[image]

Is there a conversion to Angular/Typescript?

Comment: Any app? Or a specific app you build yourself?

Comment: a file explorer
i think that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration could help me but dont know how to use

Comment: Yes - that would be the (only?) way? Unless you can make a PWA..